# Something equivalent to scaleType in a Button

Tags: android

How can I use scaleType for an image in a button?
I am using a button with drawableTop (image with text below it). I have an image and I want it to fit the button boundries (currently it is too big to fit and resulting in truncated image)
There is no scaleType attribute for button so how can I do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is android nine-patch images to be used as button background.

There is a good tutorial [here](http://www.thesecretpie.com/2010/07/creating-custom-fancy-buttons-in.html)

Also look here [Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)